# how can I select most common values in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

here is my table `Table1`:

```
examplecolumn1 | examplecolumn2
--------------------------------
AAA            | 555
BBB            | 555
AAA            | 333
AAA            | 444
CCC            | 111
```

I'm trying to make a query that returns

```
AAA 3, 555 2
```

the most frequent value in column1 and the frequency, and the same for the column 2.
can I do it with a single query in PHP? or should I do more than one query?
I have to do it for 4 columns, so if I do it in just one query is better, but I have no idea

I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(`examplecolumn1`) AS FREQ FROM `Table1` GROUP BY `examplecolumn1`
```

thanks in advance

Comment: So the result in column 1 may not have any relation to the result in column 2? And what if two (or more) things are equally common?

Comment: yes, the result in column 1 don't have any relation to the result in column 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the most frequent value in a particular column, do:

```
SELECT examplecolumn1, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Table1
GROUP BY examplecolumn1
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you want this for multiple columns in a single query, just combine them with `UNION`:

```
SELECT examplecolumn1, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Table1
GROUP BY examplecolumn1
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT examplecolumn2, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Table1
GROUP BY examplecolumn2
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Well, that returns 'one of' the most frequent things

Comment: If he says he needs to get all the most frequent values, I'll show how to do that more complex query.